# How can I change the code for a Java class for an already running instance?

Tags: java

I wish to dynamically add and remove instrumentation code to a Java class file several times without restarting the Java JVM. Is this possible?

Comment: No, this would be a serious security and design flaw.

Comment: - "Is this possible?", - "No, it would be a design flaw."  ???

Comment: @leppie It _is_ possible, it's _not_ necessarily a security flaw (heard of `SecurityManager`s?) and it's _not_ necessarilly a design flaw (heard of AspectJ?)

Comment: @adamax: Not at runtime... Surely you can modify a class and create a new instance of it, but not an existing instance. That case is both a security and design flaw.

Comment: Not the same but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817670/how-can-i-add-a-javaagent-to-a-jvm-without-stopping-the-jvm

Comment: Update: I see JRebel is capable of this. I still believe this is security flaw that 'managed' runtimes like JVM and .NET is specifically meant to prevent.

Comment: @leppie First link at google: http://vinaytechs.blogspot.com/2009/10/java-rebel-on-fly-class-reloading.html. BTW, I meant AOP, I don't really know about AspectJ in particular.

Comment: @leppie Instrumentation API is available in the platform and this is not a security flaw. Of course, there's an option to switch it off with SecurityManager, but a lot of Java frameworks use that for being able to provide a programming model that keep developers sane - AOP, ORM, declarative transactions, monitoring agents - all this stuff is based on instrumentation. Depends, why this particular question was asked - patching the code in live environments isn't super-safe of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you look at the [`java.lang.instrument` package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html), especially the [`ClassFileTransformer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html).

Here is a good article: [Instrumentation: Modify Applications with Java 5 Class File Transformations](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19309.html)

For actual bytecode generation, I suggest you have a look at libraries such as [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/) or [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/).

The [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) framework may also interest you. It can change implementation of method bodies, add / remove methods and constructors, add/remove fields, add/remove classes etc, all in runtime.

Comment: +1 While JRebel looks interesting, it's purpose is counter-intuitive.

Comment: @leppie, I guarantee you that it is extremely convenient if you for instance develop web-applications and want the changes to take effect between consecutive requests.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a helper class (Strategy Design Pattern) which may be swapped for another one at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jrebel for hot deployment. It will allow you to change the code without server restart.

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to look at [ByteMan](https://www.jboss.org/byteman) from JBoss. It uses the same Java agent mechanism and specifically supports installing and uninstalling your modification scripts, see the [tutorial](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ABytemanTutorial). What follows is an abridged version of the tutorial:

For example lets say we have some running Java Process:

```
$ jps
15295 Jps
4884 main
```

We can then install ByteMan into the running process:

```
$ bminstall.sh 4884
```

You could then create a ByteMan script:

```
$ youreditor thread.btm
RULE trace thread start
CLASS java.lang.Thread
METHOD start()
IF true
DO traceln("*** start for thread: "+ $0.getName())
ENDRULE
```

You can then install a ByeMan script with:

```
$ bmsubmit.sh -l thread.btm
```

To remove:

```
$ bmsubmit.sh -u thread.btm
```

To list what is currently running just issue it without any arguments:

```
$ bmsubmit.sh
```

If you are running on windows replace the .sh in each command with .bat.