# How to run Tests when developing javaagents?

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea, jvm, profiling

I'm trying to fiddle with [Foursquare's HeapAudit](https://github.com/foursquare/heapaudit), and am attempting to set it up using IntelliJ IDEA. I have managed to get it to build just fine, using the dependencies from the pom.xml.

However, when I actually try to run the JUnit tests, basically all of them fail. I'm guessing this is because using HeapAudit requires the JVM to be started with it as a `-javaagent`, according to the github:

```
$ java -javaagent:heapaudit.jar MyTest
```

Presumably the tests would pass if I put this line in, and referenced the `heapaudit.jar` i downloaded/built earlier. However, it seems to me that if I make changes the the source, I'm gonna need to re-package this silly .jar file in order to see if it works.

Is there any way of running the tests with a `-javaagent` without going through the whole rigmarole of compile -> package-into-jar every testing cycle? Perhaps getting IntelliJ to attached the newly-compiled `.class` files as a `-javaagent` before running the tests?

Comment: You should [configure an artifact](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-artifacts.html) to be built automatically or with a shortcut to produce/update the `heapaudit.jar` file from a module output.

Answer (score 6):

### 1) Have a jar just with a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

The manifest must be properly configured with `Premain-Class` and other attributes. The jar doesn't need any other files. Use this jar with the `-javaagent`. Provided that the agent classes are in the classpath, the agent will start normally.

This might fail when using `maven-surefire-plugin` with `forkMode=never` because by default the application classes are loaded in a child ClassLoader.

Works fine with Eclipse and Intellij.

If doing this, double check the manifest syntax (once I spent a long time to figure out that a package name was wrong).

### 2) Use [ea-agent-loader](https://github.com/electronicarts/ea-agent-loader)

It will allow you to load the agent (any agent) in runtime (it uses `VM.attach()`). However the `VM.attach()` sometimes disrupts debugging and breakpoints might fail to trigger.

It will have the same issues with the surefire in forkMode=never

### 3) Load the agent in runtime.

Write your on code to [load the agent in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817670/how-can-i-add-a-javaagent-to-a-jvm-without-stopping-the-jvm). And call it from your `@BeforeClass` You will still need a jar (which you can generate in runtime if you want).

Just you need to call this (only once):

```
AgentLoader.loadAgentClass(YourAgentClass.class.getName());
```