# How to start aspectj loadtime weaver agent without restarting jvm / how to start loadtime weaver in code?

Tags: aop, javaagents, aspect

Is there any way to start the AspectJ loadtime weaver during the application is running? Means without restarting the JVM and adding -javaagent:... ?

I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/35775792/3880225 but without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, I implemented this capability myself for AspectJ and it was included since version 1.8.7, see [release notes](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-187.html) for an example.

But please note that weaving will only work for classes loaded **after** you have activated the weaver.